# Android Api call to items in list

Tags: android, api, retrofit, rx-java

I am trying to make a call to each items in list to add some extra data for each item in list. I am using retrofit + RxJava.

I need to get list of user, for each user make a call and get City by his adreess postal code.

How I am trying to get this.

```
public void getUsers() {
    Observable<List<User>> userObservable = mService.getUsers()
            .flatMapIterable(new Func1<List<User>, Iterable<User>>() {
                @Override
                public Iterable<User> call(List<User> user) {
                    return users;
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<User, Observable<City>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<City> call(User user) {
                    return mService.getCity(user.getAdress.getPostal_code);
                }
            })
            .map(new Func1<User, City>() {
                @Override
                public City call(User user) {
                    return user.getAdress().getCity().getName();
                }
            })
```

service:

```
@GET("/somelink/users")
Observable<List<User>> getUsers();

@GET("/somelink/users/{code}")
Observable<City> getCity(@Path("code") String postalCode);



public class User {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("adress")
    @Expose
    private Adress adress;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.named = name;
    }

    public Adress getAdress() {
        return adress;
    }

    public void setAdress(Adress adress) {
        this.adress = adress;
    }

}



public class Adress {

    privare City;

    @SerializedName("postal_code")
    @Expose
    private String postal_code;

    @SerializedName("street")
    @Expose
    private String street;

    public String getPostal_code() {
        return postal_code;
    }

    public void setPostal_code(String postal_code) {
        this.postal_code = postal_code;
    }

    public Adress getStreet() {
        return adress;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public City getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(City city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

}


public class City {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

getUsers() returns

```
[
  {
    "id": 1
    "name": "John Doe",
    "adress": {
      "postal_code": "somecode",
      "street": "some Street ..."
    }
  },
  {
  "id": 2
  "name": "Adam Smith",
  "adress": {
    "postal_code": "somecode",
    "street": "some other Street ..."
  }
]
```

In map function I got error "no instance of type variable exists so that City conform to User". I think error is in Models, but dont know how to make them correct. I am a newbie to Rxjava and have problems here.

Comment: Keep editing your question, please. There's still some errors that shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

This operation is returning trying to take a `User` to an `Observable<City>`.

```
.flatMap(new Func1<User, Observable<City>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<City> call(User user) {
        return mService.getCity(user.getAdress.getPostal_code());
    }
})
```

Then, here, you returned an `Observable<City>` from the previous operation, but you are giving this map a `User`, and trying to convert to a `City`.

You told RxJava that you are wanting to return some `City`, not `String`

```
.map(new Func1<User, City>() {
    @Override
    public City call(User user) {
        return user.getAdress().getCity().getName();
    }
})
```

`user.getAdress().getCity().getName();` returns a `String`.

```
public class City {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
```

---

So, I think you meant `.map(new Func1<City, String>() {`, though I also think you should be subscribing to that `Observable<City>` instead of mapping over it. Then, if you do follow the subscribe model of RxJava, then you'd likely just `return mService.getUsers().flatMapIterable(...` from that method and leave off the final map operation.

Comment: ok I edited according to your remarks, now I am getting error "inference variable R has incompatible bounds, equality constraints lower bounds: List<User>, lower Bounds: String"

Comment: Sorry, don't know what that means without seeing where the error is pointing at

Comment: In the last the last .map() section

Comment: What do you want that service call to actually do? The method is called getUsers, but the code you wrote seems to try to get the city names for all the users.

Comment: I want to get list of user with City names, based on user's postal code.

Comment: I don't think you can combine those services to "augment" a User object like that. Or, at least, you'd have to use a map with a `Func1<User, User>` that takes a User without a City variable, and do your city lookup thing, and then set the City on the User object, which you'd return. Personally, I think you should delay the city lookup request to whenever you actually need to display a User's data.